# Whats going on here? Textview cannot be applied to an int?

Tags: android, arrays, textview, int

I am creating an array of textview and attempting to reference it in android studio but it is telling me that a textview cannot be applied to an int??

```
TextView[]titles=new TextView[5];
    titles[1]=new TextView(R.id.dummy_text);
```

Comment: What is your R,id,dummy_text, is it a textview present in your layout ? if so you can not assign it to the constructor of textview., if you need to create the textivew programatically then answer of @Ameya Pandilwar is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this:

```
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    textViews[i] = new TextView(this);
textViews[0].setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dummy_text));
textViews[0].setId(R.id.dummy_text); // You can also use any integer value like 1, 56, 101, etc.
```

Also note you need to add a dummy id in ids.xml in values folder.